# Virtual site architecture with PHP queries

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have searched around but I cant find a solution, that covers all of my aspect.

I want this URL

> www.site.com/page/underpage

To go to:

> www.site.com/?p=page_underpage

WITHOUT the url field to change.

I know that I can use 301 redirects in .htaccess for every link, but the link keeps changing in the URL.

The reason is that I like this linking much better than the PHP queries. I see that almost all other sites has it as well.

But also a last question:

Is this not a good idea? Will it effect SEO?

Comment: Or is it just easier to modify my PHP include script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /?p=$1_$2 [NC,L]
```

This internally redirects "/page/underpage" to "/?p=page_underpage" .

Comment: That worked well, thanks!

But. When I type "site.com/page/underpage" it work. When I type "site.com/page/underpage/" it doesnt work *. It lookes like the linking is wrong, because all of the images and css stylesheets are not present.

* The rewriterule works though!  UPDATED: I actually found the solution for the last problem here: https://datakoncepts.com/seo